# Promises & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise, angular6

I have a method that I must implement through an abstract class, which has a signature like this:

```
isAuthenticated(path: string): boolean
```

In the implementation I'm calling a promise from an authorization server

```
isAuthenticated(path: string): boolean {

this.authorization.isAuthenticated().then((res) => {
    if(res == true) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
});
}
```

But the method gives me a error/warning like this:

```
A function whose type is neither declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value
```

Comment: your promise return something in your function. you need to return the result with maybe `return this.authorisation....`

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from `isAuthenticated`. You also cannot just "wait" here for the result that simply.

You can do this:

```
isAuthenticated(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  // return the ".then" to return a promise of the type returned
  // in the .then
  return this.authorization.isAuthenticated().then((res) => {
    if(res === true) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

And allow the caller to "wait" for the boolean result.

Note: Assuming that `this.authorization.isAuthenticated` returns a `Promise<boolean>` and you don't need to do any other actions in the `.then`, the code could be simplified to:

```
isAuthenticated(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.authorization.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: You could also use async/wait http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20d%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20async%20isAuthenticated(path%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3Cboolean%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20the%20%22.then%22%20to%20return%20a%20promise%20of%20the%20type%20returned%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20in%20the%20.then%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20res%20%3D%20await%20this.authorization.isAuthenticated()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(res%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @JohnnyHK Probably, but I did not want to assume too much or change too much from what they had. But I did realize that the `.then` is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes. Not as familiar yet with that syntax, but the ultimate point is that the code won't stop and wait for the result: you need to have the caller "wait" for it with some syntax.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that I'm implementing an abstract method that just returns a boolean not Promise<boolean>.

Comment: @TomKurian Since `this.authorization.isAuthenticated` returns a promise, you can only get the boolean result by `.then`, `await` in an `async` function, or a callback function. All of which will be completed asynchronously. Thus, there is no way of returning "just a boolean" from this function.